# Validating Log In functionality in website using Selenium webdriver with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click the "Log In" element present in webpage.
"Log In" element is visible , when you click on ACCOUNT element on website.

code is:

```
import  unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class registernewuser(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        cls.driver.get("http://demo.magentocommerce.com/")

    def test_register_new_user(self):
    driver = self.driver
    account_click = driver.find_element_by_link_text("ACCOUNT").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Log In').click()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
```

Comment: There is no Link text called "Log In" in the webpage you are accessing. Hence no such element exception.

Comment: "Log In" element present in webpage.
"Log In" element is visible , when you click on ACCOUNT element on webpage.

Comment: Problem is resolved . Added    [account_click = driver.find_element_by_link_text("ACCOUNT").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3) ] in code and it worked

Comment: Well you tried click on something that was not on the page and it didn't work. Now you tried to click on something that is on the page and it worked.

Comment: If you found the answer to your problem, please post it as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Added 
[account_click = driver.find_element_by_link_text("ACCOUNT").click() driver.implicitly_wait(3) ] 
in code and it worked . If you want to click an element which is a part of dropdown of main element , click main element--> implicitily wait command ---> Click dropdown element.